# How to allow user to login to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

As a root mysql user, I executed the following:

```
grant all on mydb.* to john identified by 'john1';
```

Then from shell, I tried to login via

```
mysql -h localhost -u john -pjohn1;
```

But when I do this, I get the error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'john'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

How do I allow john to login to the mysql terminal?  Do I need to use the root mysql user to change something in the mysql.user table?

Thanks

Comment: Please note that the answers below give a lot more access than just "login" or "usage" access.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on mydb.* to 'john'@'localhost' identified by 'john1';
```

Or maybe the problem is because you're not specifying the schema.
Add "mydb" to the end of your login console command:

```
mysql -h localhost -u john -pjohn1 mydb
```

Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: for some reason, i had to delete all the records where user='john' in the mysql.user table before your solution could work.

Answer (score 3):

Try:
`mysql -h localhost -u john -p`

You'll be prompted for as password. Enter your password there instead. If you still can not login, give privelege `john` to access `localhost`

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on mydb.* to 'john'@'localhost' identified by 'john1';`

And try login again.