# Docker Local Development Setup

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, localhost, database-connection

I am having trouble setting up two local database servers to run my local testing enviroment. This is all based in Docker.

I have three current containers:

1. Backend scripts (APIs and such for login)
2. MYSQL database
3. Postgres database

[See Screenshot of running Docker containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd9LB.png)

This shows how I am connecting to the local environments in my dockerfile. I am taking in two sets of credentials one for the postgres and one for the mysql credentials.

When I attempt to utilize the databases when via application login, I get:

- ```
   Is the server running on host &quot;172.17.0.3&quot; and accepting
   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
  ```

[See Dockerfile connection creds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRptF.png)

Here is what I know:

- My connection proccess in my software works, It worked in the past I am simply resetting up from scratch and cannot remember how I did it previously, I am a docker noob

So how can I properly connect my software in my backend container to my two databases?

Comment: 1) Ideally you don't use IP addresses between containers 2) You may need to run custom allow queries for those user accounts

Comment: Ive tried variations of the IP addresses, like local host and other identifiers Ive found with them. I am able to connect to both of them via terminal with the names Ive put as the DB_HOST names.

Comment: You should use a bridge network https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/ but that's not the complete answer because the database containers sometimes need to have custom grant query https://stackoverflow.com/q/2412607/2308683

Comment: How does your build system use the PNG files you've linked to?  Can you [edit] the question to describe your container setup and connection parameters, as text and not images, directly in the question?  Are you trying to make the connection from a host-based development environment or from the running container?

Answer (score 0):

The question is tagged "docker-compose" so I assume you are using docker-compose. In the docker-compose.yml you should have your three services (php, mysql, postgress). Use those service names to do the connection. Example, if this is your docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  php:
    ...
  mysql:
    ...
  postgres:
    ...
```

In the php code, when you create the connection to postgres you should use "postgres" instead of the ip.

If you want to connect to the database from outside of docker, you should add the ports to the services definition in the docker-compose.yml and then use "localhost" as address (but only if you are connecting from outside, from the inside it would not work, use the service name instead)

Comment: This all great information thank you! I think I am getting closer, but not completely there quite yet. The issue lies in connecting in the php code to the DBs within docker. In using what you said "hen you create the connection to postgres you should use "postgres" instead of the ip" I am getting back an error that is saying "Could not pg_connect to postgres - DBname" where Dbname is the database in postgres server I'm connecting too.

The preset paramaters that worked before and I am using now are DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS 

let me know if any other info is relevant.

Comment: assuming DB_HOST is set to "postgres" and the rest of the variables are correct (I can't know that) it should work